# mongoose property 'password' does not exist on type 'Document<any>

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, bcrypt

-- userSchema.ts interface

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from "mongoose";
import moment from "moment";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

export interface UserDoc extends Document {
  name: {
    type: string;
    required: boolean;
  };
  email: {
    type: string;
    required: boolean;
  };
  password: {
    type: string;
    required: boolean;
  };
  dateJoined: {
    type: string;
    default: string;
  };
}

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  dateJoined: {
    type: String,
    default: moment().format("MMMM Do YYYY"),
  },
});
```

I created my user model and the problem I'm having is creating the **matchPassword** method with uses bcrypt to compare the **enteredPassword** parameter vs the password from the Database

```
userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (enteredPassword) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password); ***
};

userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }

  const salt = bcrypt.genSalt(10);

  *** this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, await salt); ***
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

The error message is as follows:

```
Property 'password' does not exist on type 'Document<any>'.
```

and this error is on each instance of **this.password** highlighted by the ***

I have used this same method before in Javascript so I do not know why It doesn't work on typescript and how can I bind the **this.password** to the Mongoose Document

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like @Mohammad has helped you with the `bcrypt` implementation.  I can help you with the typescript errors!

`UserDoc` is a typescript interface, so it shouldn't have fields like `required`.  It should just describe the type of a `UserDoc` object.  Properties are required by default. We use `?:` if they are optional, but it looks like all are required here.

```
export interface UserDoc extends Document {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  dateJoined: string;
  matchPassword: (pw: string) => Promise<boolean>
}
```

When you create `userSchema`, you tell typescript that this is the schema for a `UserDoc` - not just any `Document` - by setting the generic variable of the `Schema` constructor to `UserDoc`.

```
const userSchema = new Schema<UserDoc>({ ...
```

This clears up the errors in `userSchema.methods.matchPassword` since we know that `this.password` is a `string`.   We also know that `enteredPassword` is a `string` because we defined the args for this `matchPassword` method in the `UserDoc` interface.

For some reason, the `pre` method doesn't know our document type automatically.  But the `pre` method is itself a generic function, so we can specific again that our doc is a `UserDoc`.

```
userSchema.pre<UserDoc>( ...
```

This is dumb but we have to specify the generic *again* when we create the model.

```
const User = mongoose.model<UserDoc>("User", userSchema);
```

Now `User` has type `mongoose.Model<UserDoc, {}>` and any methods that you call should return a `UserDoc` instead of just a `Document`.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to Typescript so interfaces are a little confusing. This worked for me!

Comment: I have similar problem but whatever I do doesn't work for me!! Please check my question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71934042/property-does-not-exist-on-type-modeldocumentany-any-any-t

Answer (score 3):

don't use await in return, so just try

```
userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (enteredPassword) {
   let isValid = await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
   return isValid 
};
```

and you don't need to salt in `bcrypt` after that the second argument should be a number

```
this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12);
```

based on [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) if you want to using salt you can do like this

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
const myPlaintextPassword = 's0/\/\P4$$w0rD';
const someOtherPlaintextPassword = 'not_bacon';


const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(saltRounds);
const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(myPlaintextPassword, salt);
```